# kubernetes cluster pods not able to ping pods on another node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Setup a kubernetes cluster using three vms on virtualbox. one setup as the master and the other as worker nodes. Deployed pods on the cluster but the pods could not ping any pods that are on a different node but can ping pods on the same node

Comment: This is portal is for programmers to help each other in their problems and propose solutions. So please try to come up with programming source code along with your problem. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: How are you pinging the pods on the other node? Are you referencing the pod name (I don't think that would work), or the IP (I think that works). Also you generally want to check the service that's attached to the pod so you can see the IP that you can access on.

Comment: I execute the ping command from within the pod: kubectl exe -it pod_name -- /bin/bash and the execute the ping command to a pod on a different node

Comment: First step in debugging - can your VM's talk to each other? Can you ping one VM from within another VM? If that doesn't work, then Kubernetes has no chance.

Which CNI plugin are you using?

Comment: Usually in Kubernetes you communicate from a pod to a service, not directly pod-to-pod; and you communicate via TCP, not ICMP, and I wouldn't necessarily expect `ping` to prove much.  What problem are you really trying to debug?

Comment: VMs can talk to one another and i am using the flannal plugin

Comment: Problem im trying to debug is i am using a service to get the ip address of a pod and then feed that ip address to jmeter (which is in a pod of its own) so it can remote run a test script but it fails to connect to the ip address of the pod which the service retrieves

Answer (score 0):

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) uses a different approach to internal communication. In the basic [DNS-operated network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) there are
interchange packets between services not pods. Some of the operations use 'NAT'-ed network built on iptables
and not low-level packed exchange. It may be needed to use an overlay network to achieve what you need.

Back to your issue. I may suggest you building services, and then try to ping each other via name using
[flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) or similar solution.
You may find the [foundations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) interesting and dive deeper in the [network abstraction layer](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/network/networking.md).